# 500 Internal Server Error CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, model

I'm following a tutorial and got the 500 problem. I'm not sure the problem is caused by model or not. 
My model:

```
<?php

class Cat_model extends CI_Model{


 public function __construct()
{
    $this->load->database();
}

function getCategory($id){
    $data =  array();
    //select one row matching that ID from the categories table
    $options = array('id'=>$id);
    $q = $this->db->get_where('categories',$options,1);

    if($q->num_rows()>0){
        $data = $q->row_array();
    }

    $q->free_result();
    return $data;
}

function getAllCategories(){
    $data = array();
    $q = $this->db->get('categories');

    if($q->num_rows()>0){
        foreach ($q->result_array() as $row){
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }
    $q->free_result();
    return $data;
}
}
```

my controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    }


public function index()
{//homepage
        $data['title'] = "Welcome to TM testDIY";
        $data['navlist'] = $this->cat_model->getAllCategories();
        $this->load->var($data);
        $this->load->view('template');

}

 }
```

Database

```
$db['default']['database'] = 'testDIY';
```

and i've autoload the model in autoload file.

If i empty the database or put some random name there, it won't show 500 internal server error, instead, it shows some meaningful error msg. 
I can't figure out the problem now, anyone could help?

Comment: It means general server error. Maybe it is a bad request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem seems to be here you have used
 `$this->load->var($data);`
 instead of
 `$this->load->vars($data);`

Answer (score 0):

you didn't load the model in the controller

```
public function index()
{//homepage

//Load the model
$this->load->model('cat_model','',TRUE);

    $data['title'] = "Welcome to TM testDIY";
    $data['navlist'] = $this->cat_model->getAllCategories();
    $this->load->var($data);
    $this->load->view('template');

}
```

you also need to send the $data to your view

$this->load->view('template',$data);

Comment: read the question carefully he has mentioned that his model is autoloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Check your database environment value `'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production')` on "/application/config/database.php" and change it to "development".